# How do I prevent sql injection on a WHERE IN request with parameterized query?

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, sql-injection

This is a next application and I am using postgresql for my db.
I am used to write my requests like so :

```
export const getOneCourse = (courseId: string): Promise<Course> => {
  let sql = `SELECT title, description, category, techno FROM courses where courseid = $1`
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.query(sql, [courseId], (err, result) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve(result);
    });
  });
};
```

But when I want to use the WHERE id IN ('1', '2', '5'), to fetch data corresponding to several courses ids, i can't seem to find the right syntax for the parameter.
I have tried those :

```
SELECT something FROM table WHERE id IN $1
SELECT something FROM table WHERE id IN ($1)
```

the only thing that works so far is

```
`SELECT * FROM courses WHERE category = $1 AND courseid IN (${coursesId})`;
```

but does anyone know of a parameter that would allow me to avoid using the array of ids directly ?
Thank you !

Comment: could you please try `WHERE courseid IN ( ${coursesId.join()} )` ?

Comment: @GrafiCode and how it's supposed to **prevent SQL injection** which this question is about?

Comment: @YourCommonSense mmm, passing it as `$2`, I guess

Comment: @GrafiCode as $1 you mean? Which the OP already tried before and which obviously doesn't work?

Comment: @YourCommonSense looks like $1 is used for the category field. `AND courseid IN ($2)` with $2 being `coursesId.join()`, would it work?